# Smart buffering in an environment with limited amount of memory Java

Tags: java, optimization, memory, buffering

Dear StackOverflowers,

I am in the process of writing an application that sorts a huge amount of integers from a binary file. I need to do it as quickly as possible and the main performance issue is the disk access time, since I make a multitude of reads it slows down the algorithm quite significantly.

The standard way of doing this would be to fill ~50% of the available memory with a buffered object of some sort (BufferedInputStream etc) then transfer the integers from the buffered object into an array of integers (which takes up the rest of free space) and sort the integers in the array. Save the sorted block back to disk, repeat the procedure until the whole file is split into sorted blocks and then merge the blocks together.
The strategy for sorting the blocks utilises only 50% of the memory available since the data is essentially duplicated (50% for the cache and 50% for the array while they store the same data).

I am hoping that I can optimise this phase of the algorithm (sorting the blocks) by writing my own buffered class that allows caching data straight into an int array, so that the array could take up all of the free space not just 50% of it, this would reduce the number of disk accesses in this phase by a factor of 2. The thing is I am not sure where to start.

EDIT:
Essentially I would like to find a way to fill up an array of integers by executing only one read on the file. Another constraint is the array has to use most of the free memory.

If any of the statements I made are wrong or at least seem to be please correct me,

any help appreciated,

Regards

Comment: could you give some info about the data. Are these only integers/only positive integers/are there any duplicates, etc, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, no information about the data is available as far as I can tell the file can contain any integers whatsoever

Comment: *"... can contain any integers whatsoever" - what is the max value of the integers, are they greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? Also having a `InputStream` buffer larger than the default buffer won't show that much performance increase in your case since you are immediately copying them into another data structure. Profile having a buffer no bigger than the sector size of the disk and reading them directly into your array.

Comment: By any integer I mean any allowed integer value i.e. betweent Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE including both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Java NIO libraries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/package-summary.html), specifically [File Channels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and [Int Buffers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html).

Comment: Thanks I think one of these should help!

Answer (score 2):

when you say limited, how limited... <1mb <10mb <64mb?

It makes a difference since you won't actually get much benefit if any from having large `BufferedInputStreams` in most cases the default value of 8192 (JDK 1.6) is enough and increasing doesn't ussually make that much difference.

Using a smaller `BufferedInputStream` should leave you with nearly all of the heap to create and sort each chunk before writing them to disk.

Comment: I do not know in advance, I can obtain it only during runtime. The problem with having a small buffered object is that I will have to access the disk a multiple number of time to fill up my array which is very undesirable since it will slow down the whole thing a lot.

Comment: it has to access the disk multiple times any how.. the underlying OS usually chunks the IO anyway...test it to see...you might be surprised at the results

Comment: Thanks, I will try testing it

Answer (score 1):

You dont give many hints. But two things come to my mind. First, if you have many integers, but not that much distinctive values, bucket sort could be the solution.

Secondly, one word (ok term), screams in my head when I hear that: **external tape sorting**. In early computer days (i.e. stone age) data relied on tapes, and it was very hard to sort data spread over multiple tapes. It is very similar to your situation. And indeed merge sort was the most often used sorting that days, and as far as I remember, Knuths TAOCP had a nice chapter about it. There might be some good hints about the size of caches, buffers and similar.

Comment: You are right, this is called "external sort" however the problem I have encountered is not related to the algorithm, it is Java specific i.e. I do not know how to fill up an integer array in one go (in one disk access), as far as I know it can be done in C++ by filling up a byte array and then pretending it is an int array.

As you have correctly stated merge sort is quite useful for this procedure, I am planning on using merge-sort during the merging phase after the blocks have been sorted.

PS What sort of information would you like me to supply to help?

Comment: @user843442: The hint that this external sort is a well studied problem, and maybe your 50% / 50% distribution of the RAM is not optimal, but that there are maybe better strategies.